# Where is HEAD in the in the tree if I merge a branch, do some commits and then checkout the branch again

Tags: git, merge

New to Git. I am the only person using this Git repository. (My organization does not use git.) Here's a basic outline of my workflow.
I name branches according to their number in our bug tracker.  I then make my changes, commit them to that branch.  Once things are good I merge that branch back into master so that my git repository stays reflective of what's on our development server.  I then move on to other issues.

Some time later testing may send back that original bug I worked on.  If I checkout the branch again is HEAD still at the most recent commit position in my tree?

I apologize if my terminology is off. Here's a diagram that I hope helps.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I checkout the branch again is HEAD still at the most recent commit position in my tree?

No, HEAD would be at the merge commit (when you did `git checkout master ; git merge yourBranch_bug1`)

> testing may send back that original bug I worked on

If testing was working on `master`, and you need to do additional work on `bug1`, you can reset your branch on master (in order to fix bug1 in the most recent context possible)

```
git checkout -B yourBranch_bug1
```

From [`git checkout` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

> If `-B` is given, `<new_branch>` is created if it doesn’t exist; otherwise, it is reset. This is the transactional equivalent of:

```
$ git branch -f <branch> [<start point>]
$ git checkout <branch>
```

Comment: Ah thank you.  Feel like I've inched forward a little bit on my understanding.